# Creating a Choropleth Map at the County Level

Tags: data-visualization, kartograph

I'm trying to create an animation of the population density of the Appalachian region from roughly 1790 to 2010 in decennial steps at the county level.

I've successfully created a choropleth for 2010 by modifying what was done in [this](http://flowingdata.com/2009/11/12/how-to-make-a-us-county-thematic-map-using-free-tools/) tutorial by Nathan Yau. I've run into a few problems. For one, US county boundaries [evolve rapidly over time](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-0lM1g9iSs) so I can't use the same SVG file as in the tutorial. I think I need to do the following:

- Obtain historical county boundaries as GIS files from [here](http://publications.newberry.org/ahcbp/index.html).
- Convert GIS files into SVG files using [Kartograph](https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py) (after installing its numerous dependencies).
- Obtain population data (with FIPS info) for each county in Appalachian region since 1790 from US census data.
- Mimic what was done in tutorial to create choropleth for each decade and stitch together into animation.

This just seems insanely complicated for something so simple and I'm new to a lot of this so I'm not convinced I'll be able to get all of it to work. I guess my questions are the following:

> Will the strategy I outlined work? Is there a better/simpler way to do what I'm trying to do?

Also, as for getting the census data, this also seems harder than it has to be. I just want a simple .csv file with say FIPS label, county name, and population for a given year, and yet the best I can find is something like [this](http://mapserver.lib.virginia.edu/) with a link to the actual source in some arcane format.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can download tables of population data by county from the US Census here:
http://factfinder2.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=bkmk